# Python 2.7.11 make segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeUAf.png)

Trying to install python 2.7 locally on a shared linux machine- I've done it successfully with several versions of Python 3, but its throwing up a fuss this time. The function --generate-posix-vars is failing and throwing a segmentation fault, picture has full error message. Python3 is working fine on the machine and was installed the same way, Its only 2 thats upset. I unfortunately need 2 specifically.

When I try to run python despite the error:
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:<exec_prefix>]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Do you know that Python 2 is no longer supported since the beginning of 2020? In other words: Python 2 is dead.

Comment: Yep- he needs it specifically, Python3 was giving him a huge margin of error with the math he was doing. At this point, I'm not sure if I could get python3 to install here either, I think it would throw the same error. (Ill try it later to see.)

Comment: OK, I just wanted to be sure. Unfortunately I don't have an idea what is kaput here.

Comment: Are you sure you need 2.7.11?  It's probably just got a bug that triggers on newer systems for some reason.  Have you tried the last release of 2.7 (2.7.18)?

Comment: Oh, 2.7.18 worked! Sorry guys, could have sworn I tried that yesterday. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you get a segmentation fault, it means that the computer is trying to access restricted area in memory. I would check that you have enough storage.

You should include more code to give us an idea of whats going on. Or show error messages. Also try using `sudo` in the shell, because it gives you elevated access.

Comment: I dont have sudo access on the machine, unfortunately. Ill try to get more code for you guys when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Error gone with 2.7.18- thanks to MadScientist for suggesting it.